# How to take data from Google Sheet and create a pre-filled link to Google Form

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

So when generating a pre-fillend in link for a Google Form I have observed the following:

```
https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/{Form ID}/viewform?usp=pp_url&entry.1686820921=Field1+Value&entry.551739295=Field2+Value&entry.1561066553=Field3+Value
```

Based on this example I created VIA the Google Form > Get pre-filled link, you can see how easy it would be to replace the values and generate this URL based on values pulled form a spreadsheet. Now when I try to do this there are some obvious complications like what if there is a space, what if there is a new line

Google Forms seems to have replaced a space with a + and a new line with a %0A, it does not seem to use the default encoded URL chr (shown below) as most forms use.

```
Space %20
"     %22
<     %3C
>     %3E
#     %23
%     %25
|     %7C
```

this is taken from :https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/url-encoding.

Is there a function or method that I can call to encode the value to a Google Form URL safe values?

Example

```
sheet.getRange(A1).getValue().someFunctionThatEncodes();
or
someFunctionThatEncodes(sheet.getRange(A1).getValue());
```

If not does anyone have a function they could share that I would pass a value to it and it would return the encode version that Google Forms requires?

FYI I have tested the encodeURIComponent() and it seems to go a little over kill on it and I get extra special CHRs that don't translate properly

Answer (score 4):

For example, the following values are converted to the pre-filled link,

1. `sample1 ' "<>#%|'`
2. `sample2 ' "<>#%|'`
3. `sample3 ' "<>#%|'`

the following encoded link can be retrieved.

```
https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/###/viewform?usp=pp_url&entry.1234567890=sample1+'+%22%3C%3E%23%25%7C'&entry.1234567891=sample2+'+%22%3C%3E%23%25%7C'&entry.1234567892=sample3+'+%22%3C%3E%23%25%7C'
```

When above link is decoded, it becomes as follows.

```
https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/###/viewform?usp=pp_url&entry.1234567890=sample1 ' "<>#%|'&entry.1234567891=sample2 ' "<>#%|'&entry.1234567892=sample3 ' "<>#%|'
```

From above situation, as a sample script, when above values of `sample1 ' "<>#%|'`, `sample2 ' "<>#%|'` and `sample3 ' "<>#%|'` are used for the pre-filled link of your URL, the script is as follows.

#### Sample script:

When you use this script, please set `url` and `query` as follows.

```js
const url = "https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/{Form ID}/viewform";
const query = {
  "usp": "pp_url",
  "entry.1686820921": `sample1 ' "<>#%|'`,
  "entry.551739295": `sample2 ' "<>#%|'`,
  "entry.1561066553": `sample3 ' "<>#%|'`,
}

// This script is from https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/70503e0ea6998083fcb05c6d2a857107
String.prototype.addQuery = function(obj) {
  return this + Object.keys(obj).reduce(function(p, e, i) {
    return p + (i == 0 ? "?" : "&") +
      (Array.isArray(obj[e]) ? obj[e].reduce(function(str, f, j) {
        return str + e + "=" + encodeURIComponent(f) + (j != obj[e].length - 1 ? "&" : "")
      },"") : e + "=" + encodeURIComponent(obj[e]));
  },"");
}
const endpoint = url.addQuery(query);
console.log(endpoint);
```

- In this case, the value of query parameter is encoded by `encodeURIComponent`.

#### Reference:

- [encodeURIComponent()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent)

Answer (score 0):

encodeURIComponent would indeed do the trick if you use JS; if you use google sheets, you have `ENCODEURL` as a function, so you can do sth like `=HYPERLINK(CONCAT("https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/<some form id>/viewform?usp=pp_url&entry.<some entry id>=Option+2&entry.<some entry id>=",ENCODEURL(F14)))`

You start with what you get from *Get pre-filled link* using field values like FFFIRSTNAMEEE (that are easy to spot). Then, just replace parts that shall be individual and make sure to use `ENCODEURL`. When also using `HYPERLINK`, links become click-able in the sheet as well.

Assuming you start out with ``` https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/``<some form id>/viewform?usp=pp_url&entry.<some entry id>=Option+2&entry.<some entry id>=AAANSWERRR ``` - and apply above formula and put "hey there" into cell F14, you'd get `https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/<some form id>/viewform?usp=pp_url&entry.<some entry id>=Option+2&entry.<some entry id>=hey%20there`